# Piano (Peano) numbers?

Tags: numbers, podcast, peano-numbers

I was listening to the steve yegge podcast (#29, around 21:29), and in part of it, they were talking about "how to tell if the person you're talking to is smart", and they said that one way was to talk about "smart people things" (I'm paraphrasing), like "piano numbers" and "lambda calculus".
I'm secure enough to admit that I'm not the smartest person in the world, but even google can't seem to tell me what a "piano number" is.  So, did I mis-hear what was said on the podcast?  Can anyone tell me what a "piano number" is?

Comment: Do you know at what point (timestamp) in the podcast this occurs?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  I listened to it on friday, and I kind of tucked the reference away in the back of my mind, thinking it might make a good blog post ("what are piano numbers, and what can i do with them" kind of thing), but when I couldn't find info, I figured I'd give the site a try.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong.  It's #29 (the most recent), and it's right around 21:29 (or maybe a couple of seconds before that)

Comment: Aron edited your post for you dwmackie.

Answer (score 13):

Being Smart and having a certain knowledge base is not the same thing.

I'd be wary of listening to anyone that is equating the two.

And in true SO fashion, I'm going to roll up the other answers.  Most likely they meant Peano:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano

Comment: That's the first thing I thought when I saw this question. Being smart of having knowledge from a specific domain are completely different thing. Though interviews VERY often confuse the two, being able to distinguish the difference is the key between good hires and great hires.

Answer (score 10):

[Peano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) perhaps?

> In mathematical logic, the Peano
>   axioms, also known as the
>   Dedekind-Peano axioms or the Peano
>   postulates, are a set of axioms for
>   the natural numbers presented by the
>   19th century Italian mathematician
>   Giuseppe Peano. These axioms have been
>   used nearly unchanged in a number of
>   metamathematical investigations,
>   including research into fundamental
>   questions of consistency and
>   completeness of number theory.

Answer (score 4):

OTOH, it might be a good test of character to talk about something completely made-up (such as "Piano numbers") and see who pretends to be knowledgeable about it.

Answer (score 2):

He probably meant Peano numbers. Guiseppe Peano was a mathematician.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano

Answer (score 2):

**Those who equate intelligence with knowledge have a deficiency in both.**

(Please note that I'm not specifying the size of the deficiency, especially in the case of Yegge.)

I knew nothing of either of those subjects when I took the Mensa exam, and it didn't stop me (blush!) scoring pretty well.

Comment: I'd wager "Mensa" caused the -1, but I'd take issue with your other statement as well.  Experts in a field may lose sight of how much stuff they had to learn in order to become an expert, and lose the empathy required to understand why other people struggle with the concepts they know so well.

Comment: Sheesh, +1 to counter the pettiness... There's a correlation between education and intelligence, but you're right, they're not equal and thinking they are is misguided.

Comment: @JeremyZX: Losing sight of something that is a reality would be a deficiency, no? And not being able to understand a causation that one previously understood, that would also be a deficiency, wouldn't it?

Comment: It is a clever quote though, nice one.

Comment: @jeremyZX: Re Mensa: Aye, I probably didn't help by wording it the way I did, but that kind of thing is inevitable. Meh :) Re losing empathy:   I don't understand how that disagrees with my view? It seems to me like an explanation for, rather than an argument against.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an implementation of Peano ideas, in the wikipedia article on lambda calculus:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus

More on lambda calculus, lamdba expression and related uses in dynamic languages:

http://delicious.com/ajlopez/lambda

I'm working in a simple implementation of lambda calculus using C#
http://code.google.com/p/ajcodekatas/source/browse#svn/trunk/AjLambda

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in a precise definition of Peano's Numbers, check out this explanation [here](http://cs.calstatela.edu/wiki/index.php/Courses/CS_332L/Peano_arithmetic). In short, Peano came up with a recursive way to generate the Natural Numbers using successor functions. A number in the form of nested successor functions would be called a Peano Number. This is a common topic when teaching Logic Programming.